# MySql query - Display Status

Tags: mysql

I have student table and studentcourses table. I am calculating the percentage of courses students have completed towards a certification. Instead of displaying the percentage I have asked to display a status as below:

```
Percent Complete = 0; Training Status would be Assigned; Certification
Status-N/A Percent Complete = 33;Training Status would be In-Progress;
Certification Status-Pending Percent Complete = 66;Training Status
would be Complete; Certification Status-In-Progress
```

How do I calculate the percentage and display the above verbage instead of the percentage?

```
SELECT CONCAT(Student.LastName,', ', Student.FirstName) AS "FULL NAME",        
    studentcourse.CourseID as "COURSE", 
    studentcourse.Status AS "TRAINING STATUS", studentcourse.PercentComplete,
    studentcourse.status as 'CERTIFICATION STATUS' 
FROM studentcourse, student, Course
where Student.OrgID='DECC'
    AND student.studentID=studentcourse.StudentID
    AND Student.IsActiveFlag='1'
    AND Course.CourseID=StudentCourse.CourseID
```

Sample Data: Percentage column is being removed.

```
FULL NAME         COURSE                 TRAINING STATUS  %Complete CERT STATUS
Adkins, Willa         DECC_PER              not attempted   0   not attempted
Adkins, Willa         LMS_Training_DECC     not attempted   0   not attempted
Akers, Dianne         DECC_PER              not attempted   0   not attempted
Akers, Dianne         LMS_Training_DECC     not attempted   0   not attempted
Alexander, Richard    DECC_PER              not attempted   0   not attempted
Alexander, Richard    LMS_Training_DECC     not attempted   0   not attempted
Altamirando, Ardella  8570_Pending_CE_NE        completed   100 completed
Altamirando, Ardella  8570_Pending_IA           completed   100 completed
```

Trying to use CASE but getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

This query assumes that the percentage levels are as follows:

- 0%: Training Status `Assigned`; Cert Status `N/A`
- >0% and up to 33%: Training Status `In-Progress`; Cert Status `Pending`
- >33% and up to 66%: Training Status `Complete`; Cert Status `In-Progress`
- >66%: ???

If this assumption is wrong you'll need to adjust the numbers in the `CASE` statements below.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(Student.LastName,', ', Student.FirstName) AS "FULL NAME",        
  studentcourse.CourseID as "COURSE", 
  studentcourse.PercentComplete,
  CASE
    WHEN studentcourse.PercentComplete = 0 THEN 'Assigned'
    WHEN studentcourse.PercentComplete <= 33 THEN 'In-Progress'
    WHEN studentcourse.PercentComplete <= 66 THEN 'Complete'
    ELSE 'whatever comes next'
    END AS "TRAINING STATUS",
  CASE
    WHEN studentcourse.PercentComplete = 0 THEN 'N/A'
    WHEN studentcourse.PercentComplete <= 33 THEN 'Pending'
    WHEN studentcourse.PercentComplete <= 66 THEN 'In-Progress'
    ELSE 'whatever comes next'
    END AS "CERTIFICATION STATUS"
FROM studentcourse, student, Course
WHERE Student.OrgID='DECC'
  AND student.studentID=studentcourse.StudentID
  AND Student.IsActiveFlag='1'
  AND Course.CourseID=StudentCourse.CourseID
```

One final note: the newer ANSI joins can make your query easier to write and read by separating `WHERE` logic from `JOIN` logic:

```
SELECT
  . . . same as above
FROM studentcourse
INNER JOIN student ON studentcourse.StudentID = student.studentID
INNER JOIN Course ON StudentCourse.CourseID = Course.CourseID
WHERE Student.OrgID='DECC'
  AND Student.IsActiveFlag='1'
```

Comment: Wow! I knew I had to use Case but had syntax errors. Familiar with Oracle SqlPlus not MySql. This is spot on and I thank you!